# Grid resizes the line based on the largest widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm having trouble resizing the `ComboBox`. Instead of being on the "Filter Order Status" side, she walked away. I realized that this happened because the size of the grid line was increased due to the size of the largest widget, which in this case are the tables.

How can I place the ComboBox next to "Filter Order Status" as it is in `frame2`, without changing the table size?

Here the sample code that shows the ComboBox being resized according to the size of the table

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def make_table(row, column, window, text=0, headings=[], image=None, letter_pos=LEFT, borderwidth=1):
    """ Returns a Frame with the created table """

    data = [[0] * column for i in range(row)]
    labels = [[0] * column for i in range(row)]
    table = Frame(window)

    while len(headings) < column:
        headings.append(1)

    for i in range(row):

        # Insert "headings" values ​​in the first line
        if i == 0:
            labels[i] = [Label(table, text=headings[j], image=image, compound=letter_pos, borderwidth=borderwidth, 
            relief='groove', anchor=W, width=0) for j in range(column)]
        else:
            labels[i] = [Label(table, text=0, image=None, compound=LEFT, borderwidth=1, 
            relief='groove', anchor=W, width=0) for j in range(column)]

        for j in range(column):
            labels[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j, sticky='we')

    return table

window = Tk()

window.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# Create the Frames
frame1 = Frame(window, bg='yellow')
frame2 = Frame(window, bg='red')

# Position the Frames
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')
frame2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nesw')

""" Frame1 content """

# Create the "frame1" widgets
label1 = Label(frame1, text='frame1')
filter_order_status1 = Label(frame1, text='Filter Order Status')
comboBox_1 = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=['Entregado', 'Não entregado'])
table1 = make_table(8, 4, frame1, headings=['', 'Customer', 'Order Status', 'Order Date'])

# Place the "frame1" widgets
label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
filter_order_status1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
comboBox_1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')
table1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w')

""" Frame2 content """

# Create the "frame2" widgets
label2 = Label(frame2, text='frame2')
filter_order_status2 = Label(frame2, text='Filter Order Status')
comboBox_2 = ttk.Combobox(frame2, values=['Entregado', 'Não entregado'])
table2 = make_table(8, 4, frame2, headings=['   ', 'Customer'])

# Place the "frame2" widgets
label2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
filter_order_status2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
comboBox_2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')
table2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w')

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it is to create a frame specifically to hold just the label and the combobox. You can then easily use `pack` to align the label to the left and the combobox right next to it.